# Getting error code without crashes after playing sound in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

I am very new to swift and programming so in this udemy project I decided to make it without looking to instruction video. So when I open up simulator everything works perfect but I get an error in console and as a perfectionist I want to get rid of it.

My Code Follows:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    
    @IBAction func keyPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        let cSoundUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "C", ofType: "wav")!)
        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: cSoundUrl as URL)
        }catch{
            print("Error was there for C!")
        }
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
```

And the error follows as this;

2021-07-14 22:03:49.248871+0300 Xylophone[40027:5196447] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x60000214c320> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46

As I said I am in a beginner state I don't even understand what does AddInstanceForFactory means.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: It's not an error. Ignore it.

Comment: But why does it appear?

Comment: You should focus on more important things, like printing the actual error in the catch clause instead of a hard coded string

Comment: I'll do so! I got what you guys trying to say.